Migrating ICEfaces to PrimeFaces causes WARNING: JSF1085: Custom scope '#{window}' evaluated to null. Managed bean was not pushed to scope
I'm trying to migrate my project from jdk 1.7 mojarra 2.1.9 and icefaces 3.30 to jdk8 mojarra 2.2.10 and primefaces 12 on Tomcat8.5 or later
I've changed all the libraries and the login page appears, but, when I try to login, there is a lot of warning messages in my console log

WARNING: JSF1085: Custom scope '#{window}' evaluated to null.  Managed bean was not pushed to scope.
mag 24, 2024 8:06:18 AM com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager$ScopeManager$CustomScopeHandler handle

Here the Bean that it is called by the login page
@ManagedBean(name = "dashboardDetail")
@CustomScoped(value = "#{window}")
public class DashboardBean implements Serializable {
       //attributes getters and setters
}

I'm very confusing about the migration process because I can not find with are the steps to do!
If I change the scope in ViewScoped everything is ok, but I would like to know why!
Can someone explain or indicating me a good guide/tutorial for the migration?
Thank a lot.


If I change the scope in ViewScoped everything is ok, but I would like to know why!

It's because the "window scope" is not provided by JSF itself but by ICEfaces.
Below is an extract of their documentation:

Window Scope is a custom scope added by ICEfaces 2 to JSF 2. The purpose of this scope is to fill the niche between ViewScoped and SessionScoped by providing a slightly longer object lifespan than ViewScoped, but without the overhead of SessionScoped.

In other words, when you remove the ICEfaces library from your project, then this scope will stop to function on your beans and you'll need to migrate to standard JSF @ViewScoped.
The closest matching standard JSF scope is by the way @ClientWindowScoped, but it's only available as per JSF 4.0 while you're apparently still stuck to Tomcat 8.x and therefore also to at most JSF 2.3. As long as it's not a problem that the bean gets recreated when you hard-refresh the page or navigate back via an outcome target link, then @ViewScoped will work perfectly fine on any bean previously configured as "window scoped".
By the way, the latest available Mojarra 2.2 is 2.2.20, not 2.2.10. And you can technically migrate yet further to JSF 2.3 without much changes. Mojarra 2.3.21 is available. Don't get stuck to old tech for too long time.
See also:

How to choose the right bean scope?.


Thank you for your answer.  I would migrate to Mojarra2.2.20 and then to Mojarra 2.3.21, but when I use Mojarra2.2.20 noone @SessionScoped bean is loaded. Probably it is a configuration problem but, I don't know what I need to change. Could you please give me some advice?

Press 'Ask Question' button in right top.
